How to Export users from keycloak having specific roles assigned
I am using keycloak version 25. LDAP is configured and all users are imported from same. Now when I want to export the realm and users, I want to export users which have specific client role assigned.
For eg, I have created client which will have ‘TestAdmin’ as role. This role I have assigned to 10 users imported using LDAP configuration from AD directory. Now while doing export, I want only 10 users to be exported in the json file. Other users should be ignored while export.
As per my analysis, we don’t have parameters to add such filters while doing export. Please let me know in case anyone has done this kind of export.
My export command -
kc.bat export —file C:\backup.json
Thank you in advance.
